# Question about surplus/excess supply

Tags: supply-and-demand, money, pricing, surplus

[image]

My question is regarding the problem in the image above. As you can see, it says that if I have 300 tons priced at 150 dollars per ton, I should lower my price to the equilibrium price of 100 dollars per ton. But if I lower my price to 100 dollars per ton, I will only sell 200 tons when I have 300 tons. So that would leave me with 100 tons remaining. Is it implying I am supposed to sell the remaining 100 tons for 50 dollars per ton?